# Positioning a background image from the right rather than left

Tags: background-image, background-position

Is it possible to specify that you want a background image (non-repeating) to sit, say, 5px away from the RIGHT edge?

I know it's possible to do this with CSS, but it defaults to the LEFT edge. I'd like the background image to always sit 5px away from the right edge instead.

**CSS**

```
#companyLinks li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 10px;
background-image: url(/img/shd/spacer.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
```

Comment: Can you not use <img/> instead?

Comment: It needs to be a background image.

Comment: Why not give that image size of your div?

Comment: You may want to add better tags to this question as well, such as "css". I'm sure more CSS folks look for that tag than "background-image" or "background-position".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Francesca

Instead writing 3 lines to define background you can use below one line code, which will serves your purpose...

> background: url(/img/shd/spacer.png) no-repeat top right;

OR if you want it fix the position in Center then, you can use

> background: url(/img/shd/spacer.png) no-repeat fixed right;

You're using two Positioning value, i.e. Center & Right which is creating conflict.

You can use one value for horizontal & one for vertical at a time.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired effect. The background image is still butted up to the right. I need it 5px in. Is it not possible to do this? I find it odd that's it's possible from the left but not the right.

Comment: @freebird I just ticked [community wiki] option while posting

Comment: @Francesca

One odd but tricky solution, add transparent 5px to image in right.

Comment: @Francesca

Well, it can be achieve, try using below code...

background: url(/img/shd/spacer.png) no-repeat top right;

margin-right:5px !important;

As you're using this for LI, this code will be more relevant.

Comment: @HigneshHirani yes, Mr.Community Wiki...This answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit the image to give you 5px of alpha-transparent spacing on the right, and then use:

```
background: url(/img/shd/spacer.png) no-repeat fixed right;
```

As suggested in Hignesh's answer.

I know it sounds like a hack, but that should certainly work. Either that or specifying a container div of a fixed width, and placing an inner div of (parent width - 5px), and make sure it's pinned to the left side, with the image to the right as designated by the above CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: right 5px center;
```

or

```
background: url(/img/shd/spacer.png) no-repeat fixed right 5px;
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this table instead I think this should work according to your need :P

```
<table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr height="100%">
        <td style="background-image:url('http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-31.jpg'); background-position:right; background-repeat:no-repeat; " height="100%" ></td>
        <td  style="width: 10px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```